# $facebook->getUser() return 0 in only one url

Tags: php, facebook

Recently we have been unable to authenticate FB users.

This happened out of nothing, no code was changed and we have since tested the code in other urls successfully. It seems as facebook has blocked our url, but we have received no warning whatsoever.

Please help, we really will appreciate it!

Comment: You using javascript or PHP sdk? Did you change anything via the https://developers.facebook.com/apps page?

Comment: PHP sdk, nothing changed.
This works perfectly in other servers

Comment: You are using the same version PHP sdk on the server in question? What do you mean this works perfectly in other servers, do they serve from a different domain, or as a cluster from same domain?

Comment: exactly the same version, different domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you as you says:

> PHP sdk, nothing changed. This works perfectly in other servers

If you move web-application from some server to other and the actual url of site is changed.

You need to change the url-address in developers.facebook.com/apps to new url.

Comment: @Pedro Esperança try FB Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug 
It should show whats wrong.
Actually sometimes issues happened with Access Token or API Key.
In my case when resolving time is important I just create new app with clean API Key, App secret etc...